# Initialization of a static member inside a global function

Tags: c++

My code looks like this:

```
class myClass{
    public:
        static int a;
};

void myFunc()
{
    int myClass::a = 1;
}
```

I see the following compilation error
error C2655: 'myClass::a' : definition or redeclaration illegal in current scope

I make the following change and everything goes fine. Any idea?

```
class myClass{
    public:
        static int a;
};

int myClass::a = 1;
void myFunc()
{
}
```

Comment: See [Why the static data members have to be defined outside the class separately in C++](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/145299/why-the-static-data-members-have-to-be-defined-outside-the-class-separately-in-c) for an explantion.

Comment: Because it's not just an initialization, it's a `memory allocation` too. Only in case of `int`s you can ignore the memory allocation and use your first code by removing the `int` to be able to initialize it inside the function.

Comment: remove 'int' from 'int myClass::a=1;'

Answer (score 2):

Logically think like this:

If you never call `myFunc()`, `myClass::a` is not defined. So it must be in global scope.

In your first code snippet, potentially you may use `myClass::a` even without defining it, so it not allowed and former syntax is **not valid C++**.

Answer (score 1):

Static variable must be initialized before program start, so if you initialized it in a function, there is chance that it will not be initialized at all. So the compiler should pose this as an error. Static variable is allocated at compile time (before program run). Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the static member data in a function, it's linkage is internal to the function. The linkage required for them is global.